# Обработчики событий для событий внутри Dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть два словаря. В них прописаны темплейты для `CustomControl`. Для обработки событий я подключил `x:Class="ModConstructor.Controls.ScriptComponent"` и прописал скрипт

```
namespace ModConstructor.Controls
{
    [ContentProperty("Content")]
    public partial class ScriptComponent : Control
```

для моего `ScriptComponent`

и `x:Class="ModConstructor.Controls.PropertyField"`

```
namespace ModConstructor.Controls
{
    public partial class PropertyField : Control
```

для моего `PropertyField`.

Однако я до сих пор получаю ошибку `Разделяемые объявления "App" не должны указывать различные базовые классы.` Что тут не так? Ведь до этого, когда они оба ссылались на `x:Class="ModConstructor.App"`, он ругался, что внутри `App` эти два контролса создают дополнительные `InitializeComponent()`

P.S. При двойном нажатии на ошибку он открывает сам `App.xaml` подчеркивает красным `public partial class`**App**`: Application`, однако ничего конкретного не говорит.

---

**UPD**
App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="ModConstructor.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionaries/Basic.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionaries/ComboBox.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionaries/Converter.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionaries/Datatemplates.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionaries/List.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionaries/Palete.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionaries/ScrollBar.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionaries/Tabs.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionaries/Window.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionaries/XCTK.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

App.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows;

namespace ModConstructor
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Я вот лично ничего не понял

Comment: Я тоже ничего не понимаю. Как `CustomControl`, описанному в словаре ресурсов, добавить обработчики событий? Вариант с `mycontrol.Click += OnClick` внутри `MainWindow` не предлагать.
Когда все было в `App.xaml`, я ссылался на методы внутри `App.xaml.cs`. Теперь это невозможно.

Comment: Тут скорее вопрос — зачем? Если все экземпляры контрола должны одинаково реагировать на клик, то зачем вам какой-то явный подписчик и прочее? Поместите логику внутри кода контрола.

Comment: Ну так мне надо будет в любом случае писать `mybutton.Click += OnClick`. Я же говорю. раньше я по человечески мог прописать в разметке `Click="OnClick"` и уже в `App.xaml.cs`: `private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {}`.

Comment: Зачем в `App.xaml.cs`? У контрола нету своего файла для кода?

Comment: Это не `UserControl`, это `CustomControl`. В одном файле у него свойства, в `App.xaml` у него стиль с разметкой, соответственно и обработчики нужно писать в том классе, который указан в разметке в самом верху (`<Application x:Class="ModConstructor.App"`)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84315/discussion-between-eevee-and--nop).

Comment: Ну у custom control тоже есть код, а в чем проблема?

Comment: Проблемма в том, что как привязать `Click` в разметке к функции в файле кода? Все в чате.

Comment: Не пишите `Click` в разметке, пишите в cs-коде

Comment: Покажите app.xaml и какие using у вас в app.xaml.cs

Comment: Добавил, но смотреть там по сути не на что.

Comment: Теперь стоит вот этот вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/892386/wpf-setter-стиля-для-элемента-внутри-usercontrol?noredirect=1#comment1458311_892386 . Теперь обработчики работают, но не работают триггеры.

Comment: @Eevee: Я посмотрю, когда доберусь до компьютера надолго