# WPF: setter стиля для элемента внутри UserControl

Tags: wpf

Мне надо описать триггеры для изменения внешнего вида моего `UserControl`. Я написал стиль `<Style TargetType="{x:Type Controls:PropertyField}">` внутри `<UserControl.Style>`. Проблема в том, что, например, триггер

```
<Trigger Property="Error" Value="">
  <Setter TargetName="Asterisk" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
</Trigger>
```

не распознает имя `Asterisk`, хотя у меня элемент с таким именем меня внутри контрола определен.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь стилизовать UserControl, это неверно, он для этого не предназначен. Если вам нужна стилизация, вам нужен скорее всего custom control.

Comment: Тогда мы возвращаемся к этому вопросу: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/891623/Обработчики-событий-для-событий-внутри-dictionary

Comment: Суть в следующем: есть элемент, внутри которого есть кнопки и поля ввода. В зависимости от состояния элемента эти кнопки и поля ввода должны появляться/исчезать. Под состоянием элемента я подразумеваю так же "врожденные" свойства типа `isEnabled`. Так же где то должна обрабатываться логика взаимодействия пользователя с этими элементами. Сначала у меня и был `CustomControl`, но при помещении его стиля в словарь обработчики переставали работать. Теперь обработчики будут работать, но не работают триггеры.